# HA Proxy fails to recognize Tomcat:8080 running on a mac

Tags: macos, tomcat7, haproxy

Can someone help be understand why haproxy fails to detect my tomcat instance running on port 8080?  I can reach the server just fine when browsing to 127.0.0.1:8080

On start up haproxy spits out the following error:

```
WARNING] 141/163609 (23336) : Server cim/cim is DOWN, reason: Layer7 wrong status, code: 404, info: "Not Found", check duration: 1ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[ALERT] 141/163609 (23336) : backend 'cim' has no server available!
```

Here's the haproxy config.

```
global
    maxconn                   128
    chroot                    /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile                   /var/run/haproxy.pid
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048

defaults
    mode                      http
    log                       global
    log                       127.0.0.1 local0
    log                       127.0.0.1 local1 notice
    option                    httplog
    option                    forwardfor
    option                    httpclose
    option                    redispatch
    option httpchk            HEAD / HTTP/1.0
    retries                   3
    timeout http-request      10s
    timeout queue             1m
    timeout connect           10s
    timeout client            1m
    timeout server            1m
    timeout http-keep-alive   20s
    timeout check             10s

frontend in-http
    bind *:80
    acl restricted_urls       path_beg /trm/ws/v2
    use_backend cim           if restricted_urls

backend cim
    balance      roundrobin
    server       cim 127.0.0.1:8080 check
```

Tomcat is definitely up and running, and I can telnet to 127.0.0.1 8080 and receive an http response.

Comment: I suspect it's `HEAD / HTTP/1.0`. Try with just `option httpchk`.

Comment: That was it.  I remove the time and it immediately worked.  Thank you.